# JSF with timestamp

Tags: java, jsf

I have a jsf page that contains some javascript includes. And I want to prevent caching with adding timestamps to its urls. It it possible to do with "plain" jsf without adding java code ?

E.g:

```
<script type="text/javascript"  src="file.js?ts=#{timestamp}"></script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not quite the proper way to prevent caching. Use a `Filter` that verifies the requested URI and if there is a `.js` extension, or a response content-type text/javascript, then add headers that prevent caching. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3374703/servlet-filter-for-browser-caching/3374874#3374874) for a sample implementation.

Comment: Interesting. First time I see fmt:timestamp. Where is it documented? At least not [here](https://javaserverfaces.dev.java.net/nonav/docs/2.0/pdldocs/facelets/index.html).

Comment: @BalusC hmm, it appears to be caucho-specific jstl. thanks for the note.

Answer (score 4):

An alternative is to declare `java.util.Date` as managed bean.

```
<managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>date</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>java.util.Date</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
</managed-bean>
```

This way you can use

```
#{date.time}
```

to get the timestamp.

---

Note that I fully agree with Bozho that this not the proper way to prevent caching. The above is just for your information only. Somepeople needs to learn something new every day :)