# Disabling browser caching in Tomcat 6

Tags: jsp, tomcat, browser-cache

We want the web server to return the following http headers in all responses containing sensitive content:

```
Cache-control:no-store
Pragma:no-cache.
```

We are using tomcat server 6.0 version.

Please suggest where we have to make changes.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2563344/how-to-add-response-headers-based-on-content-type-getting-content-type-before-t

Answer (score 1):

Servlet Filter like this should help:

```
public class ResourceCacheFilter implements Filter {
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;
        res.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
        res.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

Comment: When I added this and added filter url mapping in web.xml. but 
    <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>myClientapp</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CacheManagerFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping> ` 
this is causing problem. when I add filter manager all pages become blank, if i remove then it will be load the pages. how to resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your security constraint you can setup tomcat valve to have securePagesWithPragma to true (default) which would set the headers as you requested.
please refer to [Tomcat6 Valve Documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/valve.html#Basic_Authenticator_Valve) for further details and also [Tomcat: Cache-Control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2876250/tomcat-cache-control/10504217#10504217)